# Connecting to AWS ElastiCache for Redis from Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, amazon-elasticache

Currently I am doing an implementation of a caching module in `spring-boot`. The idea is to connect with `AWS ElastiCache` for `Redis`. For this I know there are couple of ways to achieve this. I will list those below.

***First way***

I can use `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` with `jedis` or `lettuce`. That involves some configuration and I can get the job done. (I prefer doing this way)

***Second way***

I can use `spring-cloud-aws-dependencies`, `spring-boot-starter-data-redis`, `spring-cloud-starter-aws` and `aws-java-sdk-elasticache`. In this way I think it is more focused on `AWS ElastiCache` and I don't know whether I can connect with a local `redis` server easily.

My question is, are there any other ways to connect with `AWS ElastiCache` and expert opinion on what would be the best approach for this. I wanna filter out the best robust way to do this such that it will be usable and applicable in future appliances. Thank you!

Comment: were you able to finalize the approach?

Comment: @techmagister Yes, I did take the first way because I had more control and customizability. Following that way, I was able to connect with my local Redis server very easily as well. However I don't suggest you that, it is the best way because it all depends on the use case. The second approach would be easier and robust if your solution is mostly AWS focused.

Comment: what did you use to establish the connection? Jedis or Lettuce? Is that an AWS Elastic cache Redis with cluster enabled?

Comment: @techmagister I did use Jedis client. In my implementation currently I support AWS ElastiCache for Redis cluster mode enabled. Using configuration endpoint or node endpoints both supports.

Comment: I'm trying to establish a connection via Lettuce to AWS Elastic Cache Redis with cluster enabled . I'm alleyways receiving an error as "WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair" . But, checked multiple times but password is correct. What could be the reason for this? Do you have any link to an example which uses a lettuce client?

Comment: @techmagister I didn't attempt using Lettuce. However, I'll tell you couple of things to consider. If you attempt to connect Redis cluster from local computer, then there are AWS VPC level configuration to be done in-order to connect which is not a best practice. Therefore deploy test application into a EC2 instance with proper IAM permission and attempt. Also be advised whether the cluster is created with SSL enabled or Redis AUTH enabled. Accordingly you'll have to equip your Lettuce with  relevant properties and values. Also make sure the security group of the cluster allow traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My implementation is done with the caching module and I will explain the approach I took. In-fact it all depends on use-cases. For my use-case I did follow the first approach which is using `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` with `jedis` or `lettuce`. That did involve some configuration and I could get the job done. However this is not the most recent and easiest approach. There are drawbacks of using this way as well such as it has manual configuration and I had to write couple of classes with beans including whole lot of unit testing. However, I had more control over what is going on and how. I was even able to integrate spring in-memory caching and nicely control everything via `application.yml` file. Most importantly it is very easy and working fine with `AWS ElastiCache for Redis` as well as local `Redis` server.

I can briefly explain the second approach and it would be good if the prime focus is `AWS ElastiCache for Redis`. That is by using `spring-cloud-starter-aws` and `aws-java-sdk-elasticache`. It is an easy approach and quick. It is more likely plug and play. I was not able to do whole lot of changes to its functionality other than what is offered. Probably possible to do changes and I didn't go that deep. So this would be the ideal solution to keep the code simple and for deployments focused on `AWS ElastiCache for Redis`.

Thank you!